# Sign in using custom login without using ASPNET IDENTITY OWIN provider MVC.NET

Tags: .net, model-view-controller, authentication, logic, service-provider

im writing this code

```
     public ActionResult Login(LoginModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View(model);
        }
        var success = UserService.Login(model.UserName, model.Password, UserUserSession.IpAddress, UserUserSession.MacAddress);
        if (success)
        {
            FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.UserName, true);
            return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
        }
        return View(model);
    }
```

instead of

```
 var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.UserName, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);
        switch (result)
        {
            case SignInStatus.Success:
                return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
            case SignInStatus.LockedOut:
                return View("Lockout");
            case SignInStatus.RequiresVerification:
                return RedirectToAction("SendCode", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, model.RememberMe });
            default:
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid login attempt.");
                return View(model);
        }
```

so it was not authenticating the _login partial page
 as shown below`else`

```
    @if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        <li>
            @Html.ActionLink(User.Identity.Name, "Manage", "Account", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "", title = "Manage" })
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="javascript:document.getElementByUserId('logoutForm').submit()">Log off</a>
            @using (Html.BeginForm("LogOff", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "logoutForm", @class = "" }))
            {
                @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                @*<a href="javascript:document.getElementByUserId('logoutForm').submit()">Log off</a>*@
            }
        </li>
}
else
{
            <li>@Html.ActionLink("Register", "Register", "User", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { id = "registerLink", @class = "" })</li>
            <li>@Html.RouteLink("Log in", "Login", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { id = "loginLink", @class = "" })</li>
    }
</ul>
```

so can anyone suggest me how should I set user session after Login is sucess?

Comment: why do you redirect to login after success authentication?

Comment: He is not redirecting to login on success.

Comment: I think his problem is with FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.UserName, true); that is not setting user identity